# Laravel Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server ONLY ON HTTPS

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, https, web-deployment

I have deployed my 7.11.0 version Laravel app to production. Everything went well except when I try to access my website over HTTPS I get the "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." error.
If I access my site over HTTP it works normally. I have tried updating my APP_URL in .env file to HTTPS but that doesn't make a difference.

In my public directory the .htaccess file is the default one.
In my root directory I have this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: There will be a line in `.htaccess` which has only `http` you will need to change it to `https`. If not then you have to manually set that line. Also you will need to change `APP_URL=http://localhost` to this `APP_URL=https://localhost` in `.env`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir are you talking about the .htaccess in root directory or public directory? Could you provide an example of that line?

Comment: Well for now i am outside, so i dont have that sample file. and yes file in both directories, but if you have a at root directory then it will will access first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a symbolic link from private_html to public_html directory.
Most hosting providers have an option for that in the admin panel.